# How to define suppressions-definitions for checkstyle, that work with both ant and eclipse

Tags: ant, build-process, continuous-integration, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I use in a project checkstyle and I have defined a [SuppressionFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Filters) in my checkstyle-configuration. I use Apache ant to make automatic builds via Continuous Integration.

My problems comes from the following situation: I don't want to fill to much files into the project-basedir, so the checkstyle.xml and the suppressions.xml are both in a subdirectory named conf (for configuration for build). Now Ant and Eclipse work differently for finding the suppressions.xml.

Ant use the project-basedir as basedir for finding the suppressions.xml, after I declared an ant-task to find the checkstyle.xml with the base-configuration of checkstyle. This checkstyle.xml now contains the following:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="conf/suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

This way the ant-build finds the suppressions.xml, because the basedir of the build is the project-directory.

Now using the [checkstyle-plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) for Eclipse brings a problem. It looks for the suppressions.xml starting with the path the checkstyle.xml has (conf). For Eclipse the declaration had to look like this, to work:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

EDIT: Even that doesn't work, Eclipse seems to need always an absolute path.

I want to know a way, that both Eclipse and Ant can work with the same checkstyle-configuration. Someone knows a solution to this problem? Absolute paths are no solution, because every developer and the CI-Server have different paths for the project-directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Checkstyle's [property expansion](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Properties) functionality. In your `checkstyle.xml` declare your `SupressionFilter` as:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${checkstyle.suppressions.file}" default="suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

Then modify your Checkstyle task in your Ant build script to include a nested property:

```
<checkstyle config="conf/checkstyle.xml">
    <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
    <property key="checkstyle.suppressions.file" value="conf/suppressions.xml"/>
</checkstyle>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. The one exception is my error in description, Eclipse seems to need an absolute path.

Answer (score 10):

This question is pretty old, but I've found a better way to do it using the [Checkstyle Advanced properties](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/advanced_properties.html):

For the Eclipse Checkstyle plugin, the `${samedir}` property expands to the directory that the configuration file is located within:

In your case, your module configuration would look like this:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${samedir}/conf/suppressions.xml" />
</module>
```

The Ant target would also set the `samedir` property:

```
<checkstyle config="${checkstyle.tool.dir}/checks.xml" failOnViolation="false">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java" />
    <property key="samedir" value="${checkstyle.tool.dir}/conf" />
</checkstyle>
```

Comment: You can use `${basedir}` (see the link for more path proprties) for a project-relative path. This allows you to use a common `checkstyle.xml` for many projects but still store the suppression files with each project.

Comment: Is there a way to use ${samedir} in the gradle checkstyle-plugin? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602867/using-samedir-in-gradle-and-eclipse