# Using ${samedir} in Checkstyle-plugins for Gradle and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, checkstyle

I use a [SuppressionFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#SuppressionFilter) in my checkstyle-configuration. The path to the file `suppression.xml` is given relative to the checkstyle-configuration, using `${samedir}` (http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/#!/properties). Reason: I configured eclipse to use a remote checkstyle-configuration:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
  <property name="file" value="${samedir}suppress.xml"/>
</module>
```

The same checkstyle-configuration is used by my Gradle build-script. Unfortunately, the checkstyle-plugin for gradle seems to be unable to resolve the variable ${samedir}.

Is there a way to anyway use the same config-file for Eclipse and Gradle? I really don't want to maintain two files or use an absolute path in the Checkstyle-configuration.

Answer (score 6):

You can manually set the "samedir" variable in your Gradle build script using configProperties.

```
checkstyle {
    configFile = file("${rootDir}/build_dependencies/my_checks.xml")
    configProperties = [samedir: "${rootDir}/build_dependencies"]
}
```

Source: adapted from [Maven version](http://rolf-engelhard.de/2011/04/using-the-same-suppression-filter-for-checkstyle-in-eclipse-and-maven/)