# How to define a checkstyle SuppressionFilter in both eclipse and sbt

Tags: java, eclipse, sbt, checkstyle

I would like to use the same checkstyle config in **sbt** (https://github.com/etsy/sbt-checkstyle-plugin) and in **eclipse** (http://eclipse-cs.sf.net/)

This works apart from the SuppressionFilter
I can define the file **either so that it works in eclipse**:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${samedir}/checkstyleExcludeFiles.xml"/>
</module>
```

Then sbt complains

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Property ${samedir} has not been set
```

**Or so that it works in sbt**:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="checkstyleExcludeFiles.xml"/>
</module>
```

Then eclipse complains with

```
cannot initialize module SuppressionFilter - Cannot set property 'file' to 'checkstyleExcludeFiles.xml' in module SuppressionFilter
```

I found this solution for ant:
[How to define suppressions-definitions for checkstyle, that work with both ant and eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701012/how-to-define-suppressions-definitions-for-checkstyle-that-work-with-both-ant-a)

But I am new to sbt, and have no idea how I define a variable in build.sbt in such a way, that it will be picked up by the checkstyle plugin.

What could I do? I would like to configure as little as possible in eclipse, as that would have to be done on each developer machine.

thanks

Comment: For now I have two checkstyle configs, one for sbt and one for eclipse. As the checkstyle config changes seldomly this is not super bad. Just bad..

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [sbt-checkstyle-plugin code](https://github.com/etsy/sbt-checkstyle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/etsy/sbt/Checkstyle.scala#L33), I don't see support for setting [properties](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html#Command_line_usage). As a workaround I would suggest the following:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${samedir}/checkstyleExcludeFiles.xml"
              default="checkstyleExcludeFiles.xml"/>
</module>
```

Comment: Unfortunately sbt complains. _org.xml.sax.SAXException: Property ${samedir} has not been set._